# Python: looping faster using inbuilt functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took a python test where I had to code a function to solve the problem below. It passed some test cases but failed runtime for some others because it took a long time.  The function feels bloated. How to make the function faster?

Here is the problem:

A truck fleet dispatcher is trying to determine which routes are still accessible after heavy rains flood certain highways. During their trips, trucks must follow linear, ordered paths between 26 waypoints labeled A through Z; in other words, they must traverse waypoints in either standard or reverse alphabetical order.

The only data the dispatcher can use is the trip logbook, which contains a record of the recent successful trips. The logbook is represented as a list of strings, where each string (corresponding to one entry) has two characters corresponding to the trip origin and destination waypoints respectively. If the logbook contains a record of a successful trip between two points, it can be assumed that all of the waypoints between those points are also accessible. Note that logbook entries imply that both directions of the traversal are valid. For example, an entry of RP means that trucks can move along both R --> Q --> P and P --> Q --> R.

Given an array of logbook entries, your task is to write a function to return the length of the longest consecutive traversal possible; in other words, compute the maximum number of consecutive edges known to be safe.

Example

For logbook = ["BG", "CA", "FI", "OK"], the output should be solution(logbook) = 8.

Because we can get both from A to C and from B to G, we can thus get from A to G. Because we can get from F to I and access I from G, we can therefore traverse A --> I. This corresponds to a traversal length of 8, since 8 edges connect these 9 waypoints. O through K is a length 4 traversal. These two paths are disjoint, so no longer consecutive paths can be found and the answer is 8.

Conditions:
The run time should be less than 4 seconds

```
def solution(logbook):
    tpf = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    tpf_list = list(tpf)
    flag=0
    longest_route = [0 for x in range(26)]
    for i in logbook:
        p = sorted(i)
        st_idx = p[0]
        ed_idx = p[1]
        
        for j in range(26):
            if tpf_list[j]==st_idx:
                flag = 1
            if flag == 1 and tpf_list[j]!=ed_idx:
                longest_route[j] = 1
            if flag == 1 and tpf_list[j]==ed_idx:
                flag =0
            
    summ =1
    list2=[]
    for i in range(25):
        if longest_route[i] == 0:
            summ =1
        if longest_route[i] == 1 and longest_route[i+1] == 1 :
            summ+=1
        if longest_route[i] == 1 and longest_route[i+1] == 0:
            list2.append(summ)
    return max(list2)
```

Comment: Did you [profile your code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to identify which parts take too long, and could be sped up? What did you find?

Comment: I'm confused by the example, how does A to C and B to G imply A to G is accessible? I don't see a link between the two.

Comment: @Remmelzwaal.This is the exact verbatim of the problem..the last para has your answer. Through F to I.

Comment: @Pranav the test site doesn't the other test cases where it failed in run time (should be <4s). So I could not replicate where it failed, unfortunately. It only showed me cases of the first 8 cases where my solution passed.

Comment: The `if` statement in the `for` loop looks like it should use `elif` instead of three separate `if` statement.s

Comment: Those *test sites* do not ask you to optimize your code. They ask you to find an efficient algorithm. Here, I would try to build an ordered list of unconnected transit over connected way points. For example when seeing IG then AF I would keep `['AF', 'GI'], then after EK I should have only ['AK']. Through 26 waypoints you can have at most 13 disconnected transits (AB, CD, EF, ...). That mean that you will get a linear processing, with each step having at most 13 inner tests.